# Messages in NODE-RED

Tags: message, node-red

I am trying to send a string value and a number value (both together) in NODE RED to my python funtcion to execute the code directly.

The idea is to be able to change those values fro, the dashboard and when I click the "start button" to send those values to start my python code.

Someone could help me?

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69808840/edit) the question to explain what you've tried and how it doesn't work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is to set your number value and string value in an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), and then you can access them by using [dot notation or bracket notation](https://codeburst.io/javascript-quickie-dot-notation-vs-bracket-notation-333641c0f781).

You can use something like this

```
msg.payload = [number,string]
```

Because you will be using an array, you can use msg.payload[0] to access the first element(number) and msg.payload[1] to access the second element.